# Can't insert information into 3rd Column

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

I've put some code together in PowerShell to make an HTML data table and insert some information into the cells. For some reason nothing I put appears into the third column data cell. Header information does appear in the third column however. The code is as follows.

```
# Create a DataTable
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "Table1"
$col1 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn Device,([string])
$col2 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn StatusA,([string])
$col3 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn StatusB,([string])
$table.Columns.Add($col1)
$table.Columns.Add($col2)
$table.Columns.Add($col3)

# Add content to the DataTable
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Device = "Col1"
$row.StatusA = "Col2"
$row.StatusB = "Col 3 - DATA HERE PLEASE"
$table.Rows.Add($row)

# Create an HTML version of the DataTable
$html = "<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>StatusA</th><th>StatusB</div></th></tr>"
foreach ($row in $table.Rows) {
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table> <br>"

$html | Out-File $PSSCriptRoot\Output.html
```

Here is the output I get when opening in a browser, as you can see nothing from Col3 (StatusB) data is showing.

[image: page screenshot]

I have a feeling this is a simple typo somewhere but I've been driving myself crazy trying to identify it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with html but in this line `$html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td></tr>"` aren't you missing an extra `<td>$row[2]</td>` which would be the 3rd value you are missing?

Comment: Ah beautiful. This was it. Complete line to change is as follows.

    `$html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" +$row[1] + "<td>" + $row[2] + "</td>" + "</td></tr>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace most of your code with a single line if you use [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)...

```
$table | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -Property Device,StatusA,StatusB | Out-File -FilePath $PSSCriptRoot\Output.html
```

I've used `Fragment` so it just outputs the HTML for the table, but you can remove this and it will generate the whole HTML page structure.

Check the documentation link to see the rest of the options as that command can do a whole lot more.